# Where is the center of vertices from multiple-objects in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I want to find the center (by center I mean the default pivot position) of a selection of vertices coming from **multiple objects** in Maya. I thought it was the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) but it seems that this does not returns the correct coordinates.

Here is an example:
[image]

I selected four vertices, the two poles of each sphere. In red is the "center" of this vertices, where Maya place the default pivot, and in blue is the centroid as I computed it.

Either my computations are wrong or the center of the vertices is not the centroid, anyway these are clearly not the same coordinates. Here is my code:

```
loc = cmds.spaceLocator ()[0]
vtxList = cmds.ls (sl = True, fl = True)

vtxPosSum = [0, 0, 0]
for vtx in vtxList:
    vtxPos = cmds.xform (vtx, q = True, ws = True, t = True)
    vtxPosSum[0] += vtxPos[0]
    vtxPosSum[1] += vtxPos[1]
    vtxPosSum[2] += vtxPos[2]

barycentre = [vtxPosSum[0] / len(vtxList),
              vtxPosSum[1] / len(vtxList),
              vtxPosSum[2] / len(vtxList)]

cmds.xform (loc, ws = True, t = barycentre)
```

So my question is, **how can I find the position of the default Maya pivot when selecting vertices from multiple polygons?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think maya uses the center of the bounding box as the pivot center when selecting multiple components... I could be wrong, but give this a try and see if it's the correct spot:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
bb = mc.exactWorldBoundingBox(sel)
pos = ((bb[0] + bb[3]) / 2, (bb[1] + bb[4]) / 2, (bb[2] + bb[5]) / 2)
```

*pos* would be the world space xyz position to move your locator (or whatever you're testing with)

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824141/how-do-i-calculate-a-3d-centroid) may be useful for you. It shows the following:

`centroid=SUM(pos*volume)/SUM(volume)`

¡Hope this helps!