# How to update kml file/layer dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, parcel

I am using a `kml` file for displaying map with custom boundary lines. That kml file is downloaded from some website. In that file, inside the `placemark` tag **there is no** `point` tag for display icons. Eg:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Spot 2</name>
    <description>.....</description>
    <styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
    .........
    </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

That is what `placemark` tag contains in my kml file. And I need,

1) How can I add `point` tag for all `placemark` tag. Is there any way to add dynamically?. My kml file has 5000 and above placemarks. 2) Point tag coordinates will refers to the center of the polygon.

i.e) I need the following

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Spot 2</name>
    <description>.....</description>
    <styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
    .........
    </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>144.253,-36.6632,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

**Note:**

I am using geoxml3 parser to display kml layer in google maps.

This is my html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var usa = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: usa,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map
  });
    var kml = myParser.parse('http://localhost/test/DFWNorth.kml');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my sample kml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>Real Estate Portal USA Parcels</name>
  <open>1</open>

  <Style id="parcel">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>ff48a7ff</color>
      <width>1</width>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
      <outline>1</outline>
      <color>00ffffff</color>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>

  <Style id="hl_parcel">
    <IconStyle>
      <scale>0.3</scale>
      <Icon>
        <href>http://bus.w.pw/R.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
      <color>9900ffff</color>
      <scale>1</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>ff00ffff</color>
      <width>1.5</width>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
      <outline>1</outline>
      <color>5f000000</color>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style> 
  <Folder>
    <open>1</open>
    <name>Selected Parcels</name>
    <Placemark>
      <name><![CDATA[1100 N 27TH Ave]]></name>
      <description>
............
</description>
      <styleUrl>#hl_parcel</styleUrl>
      <MultiGeometry>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>-97.032117983752471,32.928768626517076 -97.024643584146915,32.923035186813181 -97.024619516424863,32.923056622674181 -97.023311876445746,32.922172553473487 -97.023027365973348,32.921986354508512 -97.022978167636879,32.921954156605246 -97.022101518923066,32.921458657105333 -97.021852382220004,32.921328433111441 -97.021603007761968,32.921212207649802 -97.021353262564418,32.921103685381986 -97.020040739077089,32.92059307329437 -97.019977072943703,32.920561642411542 -97.019978949582082,32.920357989560173 -97.019981935486342,32.920034178750491 -97.032338461906804,32.92018039810069 -97.03217983292177,32.928807043604458 -97.032117983752471,32.928768626517076</coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
.........
...........
```

Comment: Do you need the coordinates of the center of the polygon in the KML?  Since you are using geoxml3, you can calculate the center of the polygon's bounds and place a marker there dynamically.

Comment: How to calculate the center of the polygon using geoxml3? Please show me some reference for that

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you are trying to modify.

Comment: I don't know how to do it or start with. That's why I asked?

Comment: All I'm asking is for your existing code (but a minimal example that demonstrates what you have and what you want).  I don't have time to create an example from scratch for you.

Comment: Please check the code I edited it in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geoxml3 parses the KML to native google.maps.Polygon objects.  You can process those polygons in the `afterParse` function:

```
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
  map: map,
  afterParse: useTheData
});
var kml = myParser.parse('kml/SO_20150619a.kml');
function useTheData(doc) {
  for (var i=0; i < doc[0].gpolygons.length; i++) {
    var centroid = new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: get_polygon_centroid(doc[0].gpolygons[i].getPath().getArray())});
  }
}
```

To get the centroid of the polygon:

```
// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692448/how-can-you-find-the-centroid-of-a-concave-irregular-polygon-in-javascript
function get_polygon_centroid(pts) {
   var first = pts[0], last = pts[pts.length-1];
   if (first.lat() != last.lat() || first.lng() != last.lng()) pts.push(first);
   var twicearea=0,
   x=0, y=0,
   nPts = pts.length,
   p1, p2, f;
   for ( var i=0, j=nPts-1 ; i<nPts ; j=i++ ) {
      p1 = pts[i]; p2 = pts[j];
      f = p1.lat()*p2.lng() - p2.lat()*p1.lng();
      twicearea += f;          
      x += ( p1.lng() + p2.lng() ) * f;
      y += ( p1.lat() + p2.lat() ) * f;
   }
   f = twicearea * 3;
   return new google.maps.LatLng(y/f, x/f);
}
```

Note that the above only "really works" for regular polygons, so irregular polygons with concave edges the center might not be "in" the polygon.

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_test_markerAtPolygonCentroid.html)

Answer (score 1):

KML is an XML document then you can add with normal xmlDOC manipulation function eg

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("yourfile.klm");

newel=xmlDoc.createElement("yourElementToAdd");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("yourElementToAppend")[0];
x.appendChild(newel);
```

Comment: Thats ok. But I need to add coordinates as per center of the placemark's polygon. How to do that?

Comment: For objtain the center of the polygon you must get the contents of tag <coordinates> the split iand extract min lat, max lat, min lng, max lng adn finaly calculate the center