# Can be SVG path centroid calculated with paper.js?

Tags: svg, paperjs

I would like to get centre of gravity for SVG path. I am already using paper.js for paths manipulations but I can see any option to calculate this. Is it possible some way?

Comment: Are your paths polygons, or can you approximate them with polygons? If so you can easily calculate it yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747218/1869660

Comment: They are generic curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [`Path`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/) object (preferably without self-intersections), you can create an approximate polygon clone with the [`.flatten()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#flatten) function:

```js
const path = ...

//Approximate polyline/polygon:
const poly = path.clone();
poly.flatten(8);
const polyPoints = poly.exportJSON({ asString: false })[1].segments;
```

Then, there are several resources online that explain how to calculate the centroid of a polygon, for example:

- [Finding the centroid of a polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon)
- [How can you find the centroid of a concave irregular polygon in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692448/how-can-you-find-the-centroid-of-a-concave-irregular-polygon-in-javascript)

[Full example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)