# Finding an Images Contours Centroid

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, centroid

I am trying to calculate an image centroid like so:

```
// Calculate centroid
    double signedArea = 0.0;
    sskp_point centroid;
    for(int i=0;i<numPoints;i++)
    {
        double a = (points[i].x*points[(i+1)%numPoints].y)-(points[(i+1)%numPoints].x*points[i].y);
        signedArea += a;
        centroid.x += (points[i].x*points[(i+1)%numPoints].x)*a;
        centroid.y += (points[i].y*points[(i+1)%numPoints].y)*a;
        printf("points[%d] = { %f, %f }\n",i,points[i].x,points[i].y);
    }
    signedArea /= 2.0;
    centroid.x /= (6*signedArea);
    centroid.y /= (6*signedArea);
    printf("centroid = { %f, %f }\n",centroid.x,centroid.y);
```

I have adapted this from the algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon), however it is giving me the wrong [results](http://pastebin.com/WVyQ0erP), can anyone tell me what is wrong with this adaptation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have written `centroid.x += (points[i].x*points[(i+1)%numPoints].x)*a;`
instead it should be `centroid.x += (points[i].x+points[(i+1)%numPoints].x)*a;`
you have to replace `*` with `+` here.

Answer (score 1):

I looked a little into the thread you took this sample and i think that you should have
centroid.x += (points[i].x + points[(i+1)%numPoints].x)*a;
centroid.y += (points[i].y + points[(i+1)%numPoints].y)*a;