# How to find the total area and centroid of polygon using some polygon clipping algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, clip

I would like to know the total area and centroid of polygon above line after clipping. The polygon could be either convex or concave. But not self intersect.

I know there are great libraries for polygon clipping. However, I think my case is special(simpler) and I really want to increase the performance.

Anyone know what is the best algorithm to handle this case here. Any existing code would be great.

**References:** [Polygon clipping by a line](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?421920-Polygon-clipping-by-a-line) best describes my problem.

Comment: The polygon could be either convex or concave. But not self intersect

Comment: ok, I will give you some hints on how to do this.  If you're stuck, maybe I'll put some time into it.  The algorithms to find area (http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/) and centroid (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon) of a non self-intersecting polygon are standard in computational geometry.  They run in linear with respect to the # of vertices.  You can modify these algorithms as follows to fit your need: when a side crosses the line, add a vertex equal to the intersection of the side with the line.  Ignore all vertices below the line.

Answer (score 0):

[I think this link can show some light on your question.](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Math-Polygon-1.02/lib/Math/Polygon.pod) If you could provide us with what you had tried and the result that you had obtained, we would be able to give you better results.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?421920-Polygon-clipping-by-a-line shows VB code which works pretty good. Just wondering is any C# code like that. I tried to convert the code manually however the array index used in VB code is 1 based while c# is 0 based. The program I converted doesn't work.