# How do i orient my bullets in the right direction?

Tags: matrix, rotation, processing, game-physics, angle

I'm really stuck on this. The trajectory of the bullets are perfect but the triangle should point in the same direction as the player. Is there any way i can make this possible. Here is my program so far:

```
boolean up, right, down, left;
int x =-500;
int y =-500;
ArrayList<Bullet> bullets =  new ArrayList<Bullet>();
float a;

void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(300, 300);
  a = atan2(mouseY-300, mouseX-300);
  rotate(a);
  fill(255);
  for (int i = x; i < x+800; i+=40)
    for (int j = y; j < y+800; j+=40)
      rect(i, j, 40, 40);
  for (Bullet b : bullets) b.update();
  popMatrix();
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  triangle(285, 300, 300, 250, 315, 300);
  if (up) 
  {
    x += sin(a)*5; 
    y += cos(a)*5;
  }
  if (left) 
  {
    y -= sin(a)*5; 
    x += cos(a)*5;
  }
  if (down) 
  {
    x -= sin(a)*5; 
    y -= cos(a)*5;
  }
  if (right) 
  {
    y += sin(a)*5; 
    x -= cos(a)*5;
  }
  if (mousePressed && frameCount % 8 == 0) bullets.add(new Bullet(a));
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key=='w')up=true;
  if (key=='a')left=true;
  if (key=='s')down=true;
  if (key=='d')right=true;
}

void keyReleased()
{
  if (key=='w')up=false;
  if (key=='a')left=false;
  if (key=='s')down=false;
  if (key=='d')right=false;
}

class Bullet
{
  float a;
  int y = 0;
  int x = 0;
  Bullet(float a)
  {
    this.a=a;
  }
  void update()
  {
    y-=cos(a)*6;
    x-=sin(a)*6;
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(x-3, y, x, y-10, x+3, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an angle between 2 points you can use atan2 the following way:

```
angle = atan2(playerY - bulletY, playerX - bulletX); //This angle is not returned in radians, to convert it simply use the function:
angle = degrees(angle);
```

Of course afterwards you have to draw the triangle like this:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(centerOfTriangleX, centerOfTriangleY);
rotate(angle); //in radians, not in degrees
triangle(trX1 - centerOfTriangleX, trY1 - centerOfTriangleY...);
popMatrix();
```

To calculate the centre of the triangle, there is a post on stack overflow already for polygons: [Finding the centroid of a polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon)
Wikipedia for Triangle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron