# How to search point inside polygon without GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geodjango

The situation follows:

- Each supplier has some service areas, which the user have defined using GoogleMaps (polygons).
- I need to store this data in the DB and make simple (but fast) queries over this.
- Queries should looks like: "List all suppliers with service area containing x,y" or "In which polygons (service areas) x,y are inside?"

At this time, I've found GeoDjango which looks a very complex solution to this problem. To use it, I need a quite complex setup and I couldn't find any recent (and good) tutorial.

I came with this solution:

- Store every polygon as a Json into the database
- Apply a method to determine if some x,y belongs to any polygon

The problem with this solution is quite obvious: Queries may take too long to execute, considering I need to evaluate every polygon.

Finally: I'm looking for another solution for this problem, and I hope find something that doesn't have setup GeoDjango in my currently running server

Determine wheter some point is inside a polygon is not a problem (I found several examples); the problem is that retrieve every single polygon from DB and evaluate it does not scale. To solve that, I need to store the polygon in such way I can query it fast.

Comment: You wouldn't use GeoDjango just for that. You can use Shapely instead. http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/. But you are asking many things at the same time. The problem is how to store the data in the DB? Or how to find whether a point is  in a polygon?

Comment: tx @AntonisChristofides! I've added more details. The problem is not determine wheter the point is inside a polygon, but I need to store the polygon in such a way I can query fast through several of them. Is it clear now? It looks like Shapely doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Maybe what you need, then, is PostGIS.

Comment: This is an old question but adding this comment because it still appears prominently here. Using geodjango is definitely less complex than the json based approach that you have tried. Spatial databases are designed specifically to find spatial relationships. That's a hell of a lot of code by a lot of talented people. if you want to reproduce it with JSON, you are in a for a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

My approach.

1. Find centroid of polygon  [**C++ code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792443/finding-the-centroid-of-a-polygon).
2. Store in database
3. Find longest distance from vertex to centroid (pythag)
4. Store as radius
5. Search database using centroid & radius as bounding box
6. If 1 or more result use point in polygon on resultant polygons

Answer (score 0):

This solution enables you to store polygons outside of GeoDjango to dramatically speed up point in polygon queries.

In my case, I needed to find whether the coordinates of my numpy arrays where inside a polygon stored in my geodjango db (land/water masking). This required iterating over every coordinate combination in my arrays to test if it was inside or outside the polygon. As my arrays are large, this was taking a very long time using geodjango.

Using django's GEOSGeometry.contains my command looked something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

my_polygon = model.geometry  # get model multipolygon field
lat_lon = zip(latitude.flat, longitude.flat)  # zip coordinate arrays to tuple
mask = np.array([my_polygon.contains(Point(l)) for l in lon_lat])  # boolean mask
```

This was taking 20 s or more on large arrays. I tried different ways of applying the geometry.contains() function over the array (e.g. np.vectorize) but this did not lead to any improvements. I then realised it was the Django contains lookup which was taking too long. I also converted the geometry to a shapely polygon and tested shapely's polygon.contains function - no difference or worse.

The solution lay in bypassing GeoDjango by using [Polygon](https://pypi.org/project/Polygon/) isInside method. First I created a function to create a Polygon object from my Geos Multipolygon.

```
from Polygon import Polygon

def multipolygon_to_polygon(multipolygon):
    """
    Convert a Geos Multipolygon to python Polygon
    """

    polygon = multipolygon[0] # select first polygon object
    nrings = polygon.num_interior_rings # get number of rings in polygon

    poly = Polygon()  
    poly.addContour(polygon[0].coords)  # Add first ring coordinates tuple

    # Add subsequent rings
    if nrings > 0:
        for i in range(nrings):
            print("Adding ring %s" % str(i+1))
            hole = True
            poly.addContour(polygon[i+1].coords, hole)

    return poly
```

Applying this to my problem

```
my_polygon = model.geometry  # get model multipolygon field
polygon = multipolygon_to_polygon(my_polygon)  # convert to python Polygon
lat_lon = zip(bands['latitude'].flat, bands['longitude'].flat)  # points tuple
land_mask = array([not polygon.isInside(ll[1], ll[0]) for ll in lat_lon])
```

This resulted in a roughly 20X improvement in speed. Hope this helps someone.

Python 2.7.

Comment: I just discovered Geos prepared geometries. This makes operations like .contains much quicker, and requires only one simple line of code: my_polygon = my_polygon.prepared before doing the .contains operation. This produces comparable speeds to the alternative solution above. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#prepared-geometries